# jQuery Isotope Plugin - Adding inline "display:none" - can't figure out why

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to add Isotope to my new Wordpress theme. The issue is that it won't display because something is adding an inline (display:none) style to the main isotope wrapper.

It looks like this:

```
 <div id="container" class="photos clearfix isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; display: none;">
```

I just added the following CSS override to my style sheet:

```
.isotope {
  display:block !important;
}
```

Is there a better way to go about this? I feel like it's a tacky solution...

Comment: Thats exactly what I did - and it works fine. I just feel like its a poor solution. But maybe not, it does work after all.

Comment: do you have any other solutions?
i have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* EXPANDED BOX */
```

.item-content { 
display: none; /* for usability you could remove this */
}